# Is that safe (i.e. no UB) when checking if enum is out-of-range by comparing it again `first` and `last`?

Tags: c++, enums, undefined-behavior

We use thrift for client-server communication. The code generated by thrift is as follows:

```
struct Orders {
  enum type {
    NONE = 0,
    FIRST = 1,
    SECOND = 2,
    THIRD = 3,
    LAST = 4,
  };
};

class SessionInfo : public virtual ::apache::thrift::TBase {
public:
    // ...
    std::string client_config;
    ::Orders::type client_order;
};
```

Here is our driver code:

```
void getClientSession(const SessionRequest& request, SessionInfo& response) {
    // Do communication stuff here
    // ...

    // The response.client_order could be accidentally set to -1 on the server side
    // We try to detect and eliminate it on client side
    if (response.client_order < Orders::NONE || response.client_order > Orders::LAST) {
        std::cout << "Bump" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

My question is: is that a good way to detect a out-of-range enum (yeah, which should not be) by comparing again "NONE" and "LAST" as shown in the code above?

Comment: Why would you even write code like `getTheOrder();` that returns what it says is an enum, but with value that's invalid for that enum? If you want to be able to do something like that, perhaps use `enum class Orders { Invalid = -1, First, Second, Last }; Orders getTheOrder() { return Orders::Invalid; }`. Then you can use code like: `if (theOrder == Orders::Invalid) ...`

Comment: @JerryCoffin We use thrift for client-server communication and there is some enum in a struct which is sent from server to client. We can't guarantee that the server always return a valid value for the enum.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that in the question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin not only is it worth mentioning, it is critical. "If the enumeration type does not have a fixed underlying type, the value is unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration values ([dcl.enum]), and otherwise, **the behavior is undefined**." If the value is greater than LAST, you have probably already wandered into UB. You have to do the range check while it is still an integer. Once it becomes an enum, it's too late to do the range check.

Comment: To respond in part to your question, your test is not "safe".   You may also have a maintenance concern, however, if your interface description and/or protocol is updated to allow additional values of that field to be communicated.   Personally, I would do the client check in code that receives the data stream, and throw an exception if the value received is out of range, BEFORE setting the `enum` value.  That way, code which uses the enum can safely ASSUME valid input - and the `enum` doesn't need to represent such invalid values.

Comment: @RaymondChen: this is one of those times text fails---that was intended to be what you might call "dry understatement"...

Comment: Testing whether UB previously occurred is always a losing battle, your network library needs to not perform UB when converting network bytes into Orders::type. FWIW, I recommend using `-fsanitize=enum` on GCC or Clang to detect such errors at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

### Issues with your check

It is not a good check, because the compiler is allowed to assume that part of it always fails. To create an out-of-range value of type `Orders::type`, you would have to convert an integer to this enumeration type, with the following effect:

> If the enumeration type does not have a fixed underlying type, the value is unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration values, **and otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

- [[static.cast]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#10)

For an enumeration without a fixed underlying type:

> the values of the enumeration are the values representable by a hypothetical integer type with minimal width M

- [[dlc.enum]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#8)

In practice, this means that:

```cpp
response.client_order < Orders::NONE || response.client_order > Orders::LAST
```

... might always be `false`, because `client_order` must have originated from an enumerator (which is always in the right range), or an integer which was converted to a value in the right range. If:

- `Orders::LAST <= 7`, then the whole expression is always `false`
- otherwise, at least `x < Orders::NONE` is always `false`

Your `Orders::type` enumeration has a minimal width integer with 3 bits, so only values in the range `[0, 7]` are valid.
This is a maintenance nightmare, because if the server adds more enumerators, then you can easily run into undefined behavior on the client side.

### Solution

Since your task involves serialization and sending data between client and server, it makes much more sense to use a scoped enumeration with a fixed underlying type, which would solve your problem:

```cpp
enum class Orders : std::uint8_t {
    NONE = 0,
    FIRST = 1,
    SECOND = 2,
    THIRD = 3,
    LAST = 4,
};
```

The above test would still compile, and it would no longer be meaningless because of UB.

If there is no way you can update the original definition of the `enum`, you can still test:

```cpp
// assume incoming_data is some integer in your packet
incoming_data < 0 || incoming_data > std::to_underlying(Orders::LAST)
```

... as a test before converting to `Orders::type`.

Comment: "the range of the enumeration values" is [not what you think it is](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#8). For this particular enumeration, the range is integers 0 through 7 inclusively. It is perfectly legal for `response.client_order > Orders::LAST` to fail.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit good point, thank you. I've incorporated it into the answer.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reply. Really appreciate your answer. However, as the `Orders` the communication protocol code are generated by thrift, and it's not recommended to touch the generated code so your solution doesn't seem applicable for my case. I will look at another option... maybe even modify the thrift file to just take integer instead of enum.